# Discrepancy between two categorical (factor) variables predicts a continuous variable

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I am looking for the right statistical analyses to examine how the difference between two factors predicts a numeric variable in R.

This is a multilevel dataset. The factors and the numeric variables are questions that were asked from participants three times a day for two weeks.

I want to test whether participants say "yes" to both questions (factors) may predict how they rate the other question (numeric).

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your data and question correctly, you can certainly model this data using a linear mixed model (LMM) in R, using `lmer`.

You can run the LMM with your two predictors as main effects plus their interaction. That would look like this:

`m1 <- lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2 + (1|participant), data=df)`

This model accounts for the correlation in y values from the same participant through the random intercept `(1|participant)`, with the coefficients providing the following information:

```
x1          - effect of 1 vs 0 on x1 at x2==0
x2          - effect of 1 vs 0 on x2 at x1==0
x1:x2       - effect of having values of 1 on both x1 and x2 
(Intercept) - grand mean of y for participants having 0 on both x1 and x2
```

In total, the coefficients from this model provide the mean y values for all groups:

```
x1 x2 
0  0  - Intercept value
1  0  - coefficient on x1
0  1  - coefficient on x2 
1  1  - coefficient on x1:x2
```

You can visualize these means using the `ggeffects` package, giving you the marginal effects from the LMM.

```
library(ggeffects)
ggpredict(m1, c("x1", "x2") %>% plot()
```